# php need help choosing player and format

Tags: php, video, cross-platform, html5-video

I am in requirement of a player & video format that is supported on all desktop/laptop browser, and even on android and iphone, server is based on PHP

What I am right now using is .mov with H.264, which does not work on android, and sometimes not even in firefox

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using PHP is irrelevant because PHP doesn't do video processing.

If you're trying to do video processing, your best bet will be getting [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) installed, which you can call from your PHP script to process video.

You're probably going to want to store videos in the following formats, in order of likely-to-be-playable-hood:

1. FLV, Flash's video container, combined with a Flash video player.  This will hit the largest chunk of your audience.
2. MPEG4 / H.264 will play in some systems that don't have Flash, including Apple's devices.  Watch out, the H.264 codec is [burdened by software patents and a commercial licensing scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Patent_licensing).
3. [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) (sometimes known as VP8) will soon play in everything else that doesn't support Flash or H.264.

For formats 2 and 3, you'll want to look at [the HTML5 video tag](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html), which will work in all modern browsers.  Those modern browsers will also conveniently support those two formats.  You'll want to read that link for a great deal more information about video handling, including a section on WebM encoding using ffmpeg and sections on mobile devices.

(There's also Ogg Theora, but nobody loves it enough.)